# Accessing all my personal published scripts in Tradingview

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Where can I find all my personal pine scripts in tradingview that I published as either public/protected/private in case I want to delete them all? I'm unable to locate them.

I tried all links in my profile / home page (even 'My Scripts' in indicators pane) but the scripts that I published as private/protected/public can't be found.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to your profile page and then go to the "Scripts" tab. However, you cannot delete your published scripts.

[image]